# Box-Muller Type Problem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U_{1}$, $U_{2}$ be two independent uniform random variables on (0,1). Let $\theta = 2\pi U_{1}$ and let $S=-\ln(U_{2})$. Show that S has an exponential distribution and $R=\sqrt{2S}$ has a Rayleigh distribution.

What I've done so far:

Let $g(U_{1}, U_{2}) = (2\pi U_{1}, -\ln (U_{2}) = (\theta, S)$. Then, $g^{-1}(\theta, s)= (\frac{\theta}{2\pi}, -e^{s}) = (U_{1}, U_{2})$. After this, I took the Jacobian of $g^{-1}$, and got $-\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{s}$.

Then, $f_{(\theta, s)}(\theta, s)=f_{(U_{1}, U_{2})}(\frac{\theta}{2\pi})\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{s}$. And since $U_{1}$ and $ U_{2}$ are independent, this equals $f_{U_{1}}(\frac{\theta}{2\pi})f_{U_{2}}(e^s)\frac{1}{2\pi}e^s$, so the distribution $F_{\theta, s}(\theta, s)=\int\int_{A\times B}f_{U_{1}}(\frac{\theta}{2\pi})f_{U_{2}}(e^s)\frac{1}{2\pi}e^s d\theta ds = \int\int_{A\times B}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{s} d\theta ds = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}d\theta \int_{B} e^s ds$.

But, I'm not getting the exponential or Rayleigh distributions popping out.  If you could tell me what I did wrong, or where to go from here, that would be great. Detailed solutions that are better than mine are even better.

In any case, I would very much appreciate any help that you could give me.

Comment: Actually $g^{-1}(\theta, s) = \left( \frac{\theta}{2\pi}, \exp(-s) \right)$ instead.

Comment: Too much machinery. As the problem is stated, who cares about $U_1$? It is all a one variable calculation.

Comment: So, I went back and fixed that error, Sasha. And then, Andre, I approached the problem using only $U_{2}$, and got that $f_{S}(s)= exp(-s)$, which is the density function for an exponentially distributed r.v. With parameter $\beta = 1$. Is that all there is to the problem?? (Aside from doing the same thing for R, that is).